# Get value by key from Map in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following Map

```
{
"Afghanistan": "A004",
"Albanien": "A008",
"Algerien": "A012",
"Amerikanisch-Samoa": "A016",
"Amerikanische Jungferninseln": "A850",
"Andorra": "A020" }
```

i'm Mapping it with

```
  final landcodes =
      Map<String, String>.fromIterables(countryList, codeList);
```

I am now trying to extract one value by providing one key with the following code:

```
 var value = landcodes.values.firstWhere((element) => landcodes[element] 
     == 'Andorra');
```

But everytime i get the following error-response:

```
Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error Bad state: No element occurred in Instance of 'AdressAenderungBloc'.
#0      Iterable.firstWhere (dart:core/iterable.dart:516:5)
```

Comment: Why not access the element with: `var value = landcodes['Andorra'];` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are mixing country and code.
Retrieving the code based on the country:

```
var code = landcodes['Andorra'];
```

Or retrieving the country like this:

```
var country = landcodes.entries.firstWhere((entry) => entry.value
 == 'A020').key;
```

Comment: I would properly change the last one to something like: `final country = map.entries.firstWhere((entry) => entry.value == 'A020').key;`.

Comment: Note to your updated answer. You should in general not use a `String` value as "not found" to indicate that the value could not be found. Instead we should make sure to return `null` and make `country` a nullable value so users of `country` is guarantee by the compiler to check for the case that the element could not be found. (if there are a risk that we at runtime cannot find the element)

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but your updated answer is not going to work. The type of `landcodes` is `Map<String, String>` and `firstWhere` on `values` does therefore not allow `null` to be returned. So you need a cast to be able to do that. But I think this `orElse` logic is a little out of scope for the question. :)

Comment: Removed the orElse :-)

Comment: I think you should take another look at your second solution. It does not do what you expect it to do unless you just want it to return `A020`. :)

Answer (score -2):

void main() {var details = new Map(); details['Usrname1'] = 'admin1';details['Password1'] = 'admin@123'; details['Usrname2'] = 'admin2';details['Password2'] = 'admin@123';
print('${details.keys}');
}

Comment: Two things: 1) Please format code. 2) Please explain your code so others will understand it.